# R: Count number of times B follows A using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame of monthly averages of radon measured over a few months. I have labeled each value either "below" or "above" a threshold and would like to count the number of times the average value does: "below to above", "above to below", "above to above" or "below to below".

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(130, 200, 240, 230, 130),
                 level = c("below", "above","above","above", "below"))
```

A bit of digging into Matlab answer on here suggests that we could use the Matrix package:

```
require(Matrix)
sparseMatrix(i=c(2,2,2,1), j=c(2,2,2))
```

Produces this result which I can't yet interpret.

```
[1,] | |
[2,] | .
```

Any thoughts about a tidyverse method?

Comment: Is this grouped by average value, or you just want to count each change for every row and its following row?

Comment: did any of the answers solve it? If so, please upvote/accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use group by and count the values

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(value = c(130, 200, 240, 230, 130),
                 level = c("below", "above","above","above", "below"))
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = paste(level, lead(level))) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  # drop the observation that does not have a "next" value
  filter(!grepl(pattern = "NA", x = grp))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   grp             n
#>   <chr>       <int>
#> 1 above above     2
#> 2 above below     1
#> 3 below above     1
```

Comment: I'd probably use `lag` rather than `lead` and reverse the `paste` order: `paste0(lag(level), "-", level)`. This will give `NA-below` for the first row (no change since there is no prior value) and will also capture the last change `above-below`.

Comment: what is the difference? I'd suggest dropping the `NA` containing value anyway

Comment: There isn't a huge difference. Just depends how you want to handle first and last rows.

Answer (score 3):

You could use table from base R:

`table(df$level[-1], df$level[-nrow(df)])`

```
        above below
  above     2     1
  below     1     0
```

EDIT in response to @HCAI's comment: applying `table` to multiple columns:
First, generate some data:

```
set.seed(1)
U = matrix(runif(4*20),nrow = 20)
dfU=data.frame(round(U))
library(plyr) # for mapvalues
df2 = data.frame(apply(dfU, 
                       FUN = function(x) mapvalues(x, from=0:1, to=c('below','above')),
                       MARGIN=2))
```

so that df2 contains random 'above' and 'below':

```
      X1    X2    X3    X4
1  below above above above
2  below below above below
3  above above above below
4  above below above below
5  below below above above
6  above below above below
7  above below below below
8  above below below above
9  above above above below
10 below below above above
11 below below below below
12 below above above above
13 above below below below
14 below below below below
15 above above below below
16 below above below above
17 above above below above
18 above below above below
19 below above above above
20 above below below above
```

Now apply `table` to each column and vectorize the output:

```
apply(df2, 
      FUN=function(x) as.vector(table(x[-1], 
                                      x[-nrow(df2)])),
      MARGIN=2)
```

which gives us

```
     X1 X2 X3 X4
[1,]  5  2  7  2
[2,]  5  6  4  6
[3,]  6  5  3  6
[4,]  3  6  5  5
```

All that's left is a bit of care in labeling the rows of the output. Maybe someone can come up with a clever way to merge/join the data frames resulting from `apply(df2, FUN=function(x) melt(table(x[-1],x[-nrow(df2)])),2)`, which would maintain the row names. (I spent some time looking into it but couldn't work out how to do it easily.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought of table! Do you think it's possible to put it into a lapply function to use multiple input data frames?

Answer (score 1):

not run, so there may be a typo, but you get the idea.  I'll leave it to you to deal with na and the first obs.  Single pass through the vector.

```
library(dplyr)
summarize(increase = sum(case_when(value > lag(value) ~ 1, T ~ 0)),
          decrease = sum(case_when(value > lag(value) ~ 1, T ~ 0)),
          constant = sum(case_when(value = lag(value) ~ 1, T ~ 0))
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(value=c(130,200, 240, 230, 130),level=c("below", "above","above","above", "below"))

df %>% 
  mutate(changes = str_c(lag(level), level, sep = "_")) %>% 
  count(changes) %>% drop_na(changes)

#>       changes n
#> 1 above_above 2
#> 2 above_below 1
#> 3 below_above 1
```

Yet another solution, based on `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(value=c(130,200, 240, 230, 130),level=c("below", "above","above","above", "below"))

dt[, changes := paste(shift(level), level, sep = "_")
][2:.N][,.(n = .N), keyby = .(changes)]

#>        changes n
#> 1: above_above 2
#> 2: above_below 1
#> 3: below_above 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  group_by(level = str_c(level, lead(level), sep = " ")) %>% 
  count(level) %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
 level           n
  <chr>       <int>
1 above above     2
2 above below     1
3 below above     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is clever! Do you think it's possible to print a 0 for the times where no transition is seen. Eg. in your example we don't see below >> below similar to how njp's answer is in base R please?